# access items in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater and I am trying to access labels inside it. Here is my method:

```
protected void ButtonlarıTemizle()
    {
        int n = 0;
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            n++;
            Label lbl = item.FindControl("lblApproved") as Label;
            Button btn = item.FindControl("btnAssignApproved") as Button;
            if (lbl.Text.Equals("Satışa Dönmüştür"))
            {
                btn.Visible = false;
                lbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            }
        }
        Response.Write("<script lang='JavaScript'>alert('"+n+"');</script>");
    }
```

I can access inside repeater but here is the problem: I can't access the last item of repeater. I put that 'n' variable to control how many times I turn inside foreach loop and I see that n always gives -1 of item numbers. For example if I have 3 items in repeater, n is 2, if there is 1 item in repeater, n is 0. What am I doing wrong in here ?

Edit: I am writing my .aspx page since it asked

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceTeklifler" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <strong>Teklif No.</strong>&nbsp;<%#Eval("TeklifId") %><br />
                                <strong>Teklif Tarihi:</strong>&nbsp;<%#Eval("TeklifTarih") %><br />
                                <strong>Teklifi Hazırlayan:</strong>&nbsp;<%#Eval("Name") %>&nbsp;<%#Eval("Surname") %><br />
                                <strong>Firma Adı:</strong>&nbsp;<%#Eval("FirmaAdi") %><br />
                                <strong>Ürünler:</strong><br />
                                <%#Eval("TeklifSiparis") %>
                                <strong>Genel Toplam:</strong>&nbsp;<%#Eval("TeklifTutar") %>$<br />
                                <strong>Not:</strong><br />
                                <%#Eval("TeklifNot") %><br />
                                <strong>Teklif Durumu:</strong>&nbsp;<asp:Label ForeColor="Red" ID="lblApproved" runat="server" Text='<%# CheckIfApproved(Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Approved"))) %>'></asp:Label><br /><br />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnAssignApproved" runat="server" Text="Satışa Döndü Olarak İşaretle" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CommandName="Done" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TeklifId") %>' />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: 'n' variable aside, why do you think you can't access the last item in the repeater?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As you can see I am changing label color and button visibility. All repeater items changing except the last one @sr28

Comment: @KorayDurudogan - Can you show the mark-up code? .aspx page?

Comment: Here you go :) @RahulSingh

Comment: So are you saying that the last repeater item isn't haven't the changes applied that you expect?

Comment: @KorayDurudogan - When you are calling this method `ButtonlarıTemizle`?

Comment: Are you using a master page or user control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you explicitly calling a different method but what you are doing can be easily done in `ItemDataBound` event of repeater control:-

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound"
```

Then handler it like this:-

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
   {
       Label lbl = e.Item.FindControl("lblApproved") as Label;
       Button btn = e.Item.FindControl("btnAssignApproved") as Button;
       if (lbl.Text.Equals("Satışa Dönmüştür"))
       {
           btn.Visible = false;
           lbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
       }
   }
}
```

Please note there is no need to do any loop on your repeater items. Repeater `ItemDataBound` event will fire for each item when it is bounded. Also, if you want to have a `count` simply declare a variable outside this method and increment it inside this event.